# MVC-AJAX iterate <div> for no of data in ajax success has

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I looked at many sites but I didn't get an answer. Might be I am new to MVC that's why I couldn't recognize it if its an answer. Everybody describes for the only an alert message to come but what if I want to iterate entire `<div>` inside `$.each`?

Scenario is. I have APIController in MVC project. I call to API method from ajax and get data successfully. but I have used one theme for styling my application. That theme uses various div tags with different classes to show info on the card.

I tried to add `.html()` method and add all the div elements as string format in the ajax success method.

Another try was using `$.each` and give model value to div id.

I also created a partial view but didn't get it how to loop through all the div and display the new value at each iteration.

Here is my code :

```
// HTML
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-10 background2" id="searchResult" style="margin-top:20px;">
</div>

// JQUERY
 $('#search').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/RegisterUsersAPI",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {                        //$('#searchResultDoctors').html("/Home/_EmpList.cshtml"); // tried for partial view
                        $.each(data, function (index,item) {
                            $('#searchResult').html(
                                '<div class= "x_panel" >'+
                                ' <div class="x_content">'+
                                        '<div class="row">'+
                                         '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
                                         ' <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile_details">'+
                                                '<div class="well profile_view">'+
                                                     '<div class="col-sm-12">'+
                                                         '<h4 class="brief" id="divSpeciality"><i>'+item.Speciality+'</i></h4>'+
                                                        '<div class="left col-xs-7">'+
                                                            '<h2 id="divFullName">' + item.FullName +'</h2>'+
                                                            '<p id="divEducation">'+ item.Education +'</p>'+
                                                        '</div>'+
                                                        '<div class="right col-md-5">'+
                                                            '<img src="~/Images/img.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">'+
                                                        '</div>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                  '</div>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                         '</div>'+
                                      '</div>'+
                                 '</div>'
                                );
                        });

                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("fail");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });

            });
```

how to show details got from API to this kind of div arrangement?

Please help. thanks

**EDIt**

sorry for being a little bit unclear. the above code generates card in line by line. in the theme, it was arranged in a table like structure using `col-md-*` classes. So is there a way to achieve table structure using these classes?

Comment: do you want to put it in a table or have 3 columns in a row?, because it seems it generates 1 column in a row now. your problem is likely a css issue

Comment: yes exactly.. how to adjust css content from ajax call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to clean up the html string concatenation, see javascript code below, use `instead of`+` for building strings

Though I don't know your css classes but replace your html with this code below

```
<div class="background2" id="searchResult" style="margin-top:20px;">
</div>
```

then your javascript can be as below, also see suggestion on cleaner way of concatenating html strings without using `+`

```
var divContent = '';
 $.ajax({
     url: "/api/RegisterUsersAPI",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {  
         $.each(data, function (index, item) {
              divContent +=
            `<div class="col-md-4">
                <div class= "x_panel" >
                    <div class="x_content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile_details">
                                    <div class="well profile_view">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <h4 class="brief" id="divSpeciality"><i>${item.Speciality}</i></h4>
                                            <div class="left col-xs-7"><h2 id="divFullName">${item.FullName}</h2>
                                                <p id="divEducation">${item.Education}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="right col-md-5">
                                                <img src="~/Images/img.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
            });
            $('#searchResult').html(
                divContent
            );
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert("fail");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! `<div class="col-md-4">` That's what I needed to add !!

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't clear. As far as I understand you want to add data list item one by one to the html tag.

```js
$('#search').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/RegisterUsersAPI",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {                        //$('#searchResultDoctors').html("/Home/_EmpList.cshtml"); // tried for partial view
                        var items='';
                        $.each(data, function (index,item) {
                            
                            items += '<div class= "x_panel" >'+
                                ' <div class="x_content">'+
                                        '<div class="row">'+
                                         '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
                                         ' <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile_details">'+
                                                '<div class="well profile_view">'+
                                                     '<div class="col-sm-12">'+
                                                         '<h4 class="brief" id="divSpeciality"><i>'+item.Speciality+'</i></h4>'+
                                                        '<div class="left col-xs-7">'+
                                                            '<h2 id="divFullName">' + item.FullName +'</h2>'+
                                                            '<p id="divEducation">'+ item.Education +'</p>'+
                                                        '</div>'+
                                                        '<div class="right col-md-5">'+
                                                            '<img src="~/Images/img.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">'+
                                                        '</div>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                  '</div>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                         '</div>'+
                                      '</div>'+
                                 '</div>'
                                
                        });
                        $('#searchResult').html(items);
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("fail");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });

            });
```